# SQL Sum of two columns with different types and negative/positive numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns and I want get sum of this two.

```
 POINTS    BONUS_POINTS
 -----------------------
   5         -1
   4         0.4
   7         -0.5
```

But it's problem, that one column is of type integer and another is of type double. `BONUS_POINTS` can be negative on positive.

I want have result like

```
 POINTS    BONUS_POINTS     SUM
 ------------------------------------
   5         -1              4
   4         0.4             4,4
   7         -0.5            6.5
```

It's my query and my false result. I really not understand from where come these values.

```
      SELECT PLAYER_NICKNAME, SUM(GAME_POINTS) AS POINTS,
             SUM(GAME_BONUSPOINTS) AS BONUS_POINTS,
             SUM(CAST(POINTS AS float) + CAST(GAME_BONUSPOINTS AS float)) AS SUM
      FROM PLAYERS, GAMES
      WHERE PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID = GAMES.GAME_PLAYERS_PLAYERID
      GROUP BY PLAYERS.PLAYER_NICKNAME
 SUM
 ----
 1.5
 3.5
 3.45
```

Comment: Please provide DDLs with insert script and expected output.

Comment: TRY THIS `CAST( SUM(GAME_BONUSPOINTS + GAME_BONUSPOINTS) AS FLOAT) AS [SUM]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query is totally bogus.  `ROLES` is not being used.  And you need to learn proper `JOIN` syntax.

Second, you can add integers and floating point numbers without an explicit cast.

I would suggest:

```
SELECT p.PLAYER_NICKNAME,
       SUM(g.GAME_POINTS) as POINTS,
       SUM(g.GAME_BONUSPOINTS) as BONUS_POINTS,
       SUM(g.GAME_BONUSPOINTS) + SUM(g.GAME_BONUSPOINTS) as total
FROM PLAYERS p JOIN
     GAMES g
     ON p.PLAYER_ID = g.GAME_PLAYERS_PLAYERID
GROUP BY p.PLAYER_NICKNAME;
```

If the sum is wrong in your query, then it is probably because the `roles` table is not being properly joined in.

Comment: thank you. I use table `ROLES` my query isn't full. I used only this what I don't understand and I forgot delete `ROLES` from query. What about `JOIN` it's the same as `FROM PLAYERS, GAMES
      WHERE PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID = GAMES.GAME_PLAYERS_PLAYERID`. Thank you! I did it wrong with sum

Answer (score 1):

You are  using the same field twice in your code;

```
SUM(CAST(GAME_BONUSPOINTS AS float) + CAST(GAME_BONUSPOINTS AS float))
```

should be

```
SUM(CAST(GAME_BONUSPOINTS AS float) + CAST(GAME_POINTS AS float))
```

Comment: In your last edit you changed to sum on POINTS but that is the sum of GAME_POINTS so it doesn't make sense. Replace POINTS with GAME_POINTS as I wrote. Also, as @Gordon Linoff writes below, remove ROLES from FROM row since you're not using that table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
select *, CAST(POINTS AS float) + CAST(BONUS_POINTS AS float) AS SUM 
FROM ( SELECT PLAYER_NICKNAME, SUM(GAME_POINTS) AS POINTS,
             SUM(GAME_BONUSPOINTS) AS BONUS_POINTS
      FROM PLAYERS, GAMES, ROLES
      WHERE PLAYERS.PLAYER_ID = GAMES.GAME_PLAYERS_PLAYERID
      GROUP BY PLAYERS.PLAYER_NICKNAME)
```